# I have LastPass on Firefox; I want to copy LastPass with all my passwords to Google Chrome

Tags: windows-10

How do I set up LastPass on Google Chrome and then bring all my passwords from LastPass on Firefox?

Comment: LastPass is a Firefox and Chrome extension.  You install the extension on both browsers and your passwords are automatically accessible after you log into your Lastpass account.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy anything. LastPass is cloud based and will retain all of your data, no matter which device you log into it from. You just need to install the LastPass extension on Google Chrome, and then log into your LastPass account using the extension you just installed in Google Chrome.